# Why are some of my richfaces resources missing on some pages and not on others?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a `rich:panelMenu` and inside that a `rich:panelMenuItem` that has a bunch of menu navigation links. If I click on these a link for example named `Settings` my buttons and some resources like images and css stuff aren't showing up in my console. I have around 15 nav links on my sidebar and the resources only load on two of those.

I am stumped because if I click on a link from within the page that takes me to the same `Settings` page all the resources are loading.

It also seems that when clicking on the nav links that don't work I am getting the resources for the previous page.

Any insight would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first page is inside WEB-INF? Maybe this problem is because your resources are inside WEb-INF folder.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason.